# Extracting numerical cell based on color to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

If the number is Light-blue Id like to extract the value with the name (column A is the name) to another sheet.

So far I have a working formula that extracts the numerical value. I'm just having trouble extracting the number and name to another sheet, which is the second formula that I have listed. I'd also like to learn what each line of code does. 
Anything is appreciated, thanks for your help

```
Function GetColorNum(prange As Range) As Double
 Dim xOut As Double
 Dim i As Long

 For i = 1 To 100

    If prange.Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 33 Then
    xOut = prange.Value

    End If

Next
GetColorNum = xOut

End Function


Sub tickerextract()
Dim c As Range
Dim ticker As String

    If GetColorNum = True Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy
            c.offset(0, 1) = ticker

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: removed formula tag since there are no formulas in this question (only VBA procedures and functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, it's simpler than originally written.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TickerExtract()

    Dim rngTicker As Range
    Set rngTicker = Worksheets("Tickers").Range("B1:B100") 'change as needed, assumes value in column B

    Dim rngCel As Range

    For Each rngCel In rngTicker

        If rngCel.Font.ColorIndex = 33 Then

           'change name as needed and column references
            Worksheets("Other").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(1, 2).Value = Array(rngCel.Offset(, -1).Value, rngCel.Value)

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Please ask another question @leoj. It will be cleaner and clearer that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (arbitrary start column for source range and arbitrary Destination range):

```
If prange.Cells.Font.ColorIndex=33 Then
     Sheets("NAME").Cells(blah, 1).Copy Sheets("NAME2").Cells(moo, rawr)
End If
```

You would want this within your loop so that each value as it iterates through the cells and copy/pastes if true.